# Place a view exactly over another view using view.animate()

Tags: java, android, android-animation, translate-animation

I want to move a view in the place of another view using the view.animate() method.

So this is the scenario:

I have the following layout:
[Initial layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ma6R.png) (screenshot)

And when a tap/clicks the red image, I want that the image to be moved (i.e. animated/translated) exactly in the place where the cloud frame is.
But, when I use this code:

```
view.animate().x(target.getX()).y(target.getY()).setDuration(200).start();
```

The result is the following:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLWq5.jpg) (screenshot)

What are the real coordinates of the target view? Why is the image not placed exactly in the bounds of the target view? The views have the same size.

Comment: I am wondering if the margin/padding is the issue. if you set them on either of the views, can you remove them and see what happens. if it is the issue then just subtract this margin/padding when calculating target X and Y.

Comment: The views are clean. I didn't set any margin or padding.

Answer (score 1):

If you use target.getX() you don't get the absolute x position on the screen.
I suggest you to use
View.getLocationOnScreen()